# OpenCV: Background subtraction 0xC0000005: Access violation writing locatio

Tags: c++, opencv, background-subtraction, mog

I am new to opencv and I am trying to use `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2`. But, i have a problem with access violation (I could not find a solution for this anywhere). I am not sure, if the problem is with my code? Please help!!

THE PROBLEM:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000007F81A1F3F33 (igdfcl64.dll) in opencv_31_test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000067648A80.
```

I am using VS2013 with opencv 3.1.

here is the code:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    bool update = false;

    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"camera not open";
        return -1;
    }
    Mat frames, bg_mask, output, image;
    cap >> image;
    if (image.empty())
    {
        cout<<"no image from camera";
        return -1;
    }
    resize(image, frames, Size(640, 480));
    namedWindow("webcam", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("segmented", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    Ptr<BackgroundSubtractorMOG2> bg_sub = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
    bg_sub->setVarThreshold(10);
    for (;;)
    {
        cap >> frames;
        if (frames.empty())
            break;
        bg_sub->apply(frames, bg_mask, update ? -1 : 0);
        imshow("webcam", frames);
        imshow("segmented", output);
        if (waitKey(30) == 27)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you never put anything in the output image (not sure if this fix the error)... by the way, it would be nice to see the stacktrace of it to know what could be the error

Comment: imshow("segmented", bg_mask);

Comment: @sturkmen changed it to what you mentioned. but, the problem is still there.

Comment: @api55 the stack call is in the link  http://www84.zippyshare.com/v/HX9ytB8l/file.html

Comment: @PratulJn did you try removing the `imshow("segmented", output);` . The variable `output` is never set.... btw, you need to compile it in debug mode... your stacktrace just says a bunch of unknowns...

Comment: as @PratulJn said output is NULL and good line is imshow("segmented", bg_mask);

Comment: @api55  I changed that line to imshow("segmented", bg_mask);  I compiled and run it again in debug mode itself. but doesnt work.

Comment: the problem occurs in the line            bg_sub->apply(frames, bg_mask, update ? -1 : 0);

Comment: @PratulJn what error does it gives you? is it an assert error?

Comment: @api55  it is stated above. Unhandled exception with Access violation writing when that line executed.